Inverse of a conditional CDF function
I'm struggling a bit to understand a potential easy concept due to the lack of literature regarding it (or, at least, the one that I saw).
I have the following CDF: $F(v^*|\pi^e)=B/w\equiv\omega$.
Since the CDF is monotonically increasing, we can derive its inverse; the paper I'm following derived then the following:
$\nu^*=\pi^e+F^{-1}(\omega)$.
Well, why is this the case? Thanks

How are all those symbols related? It looks to me as if your cdf is the constant $B/w$, so there's that.

$B=\int_{0}^{1}b^i\ di$ where $b_i\in[0,w_i]$ where i is an index fot the i-individual. But maybe I asked the question in a wrong way, I'm more wondering for a rule of the inverse of a conditional CDF. Thanks
